# Persisting VNFeaturePrintObservation to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, coreml

I am working with the `Photos` and `CoreML` frameworks in Swift to implement some image analysis functionality in an App I'm working on. I require the ability to store the result of `VNGenerateImageFeaturePrintRequest()`, which has type `VNFeaturePrintObservation`.

These results need to be persisted for each image so that they can be used later without re-calculating, as it is a slow process. `VNFeaturePrintObservation` doesn't conform to `Codable`, so I can't use something like a `JSONEncoder` which is how I've previously persisted data like this into Core Data.

Is there a way I can persist my `VNFeaturePrintObservation` objects in Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `VNFeaturePrintObservation`, but [the docs say](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnfeatureprintobservation) that

- It's a subclass of `VNObservation`, and
- `VNObservation` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`

That means that `VNFeaturePrintObservation` also conforms to `NSSecureCoding`. Any class that conforms to `NSSecureCoding` can be saved in Core Data by using a Core Data attribute with the type set to "Transformable". Thanks to `NSSecureCoding` there's no additional work.

That would look like this in the Core Data model editor:

[image: Core Data model editor for transformable type]

Two things to notice:

- Type is "Transformable"
- Custom class is `VNFeaturePrintObservation`

If you have Xcode generate your source code, the property will look like this:

```
@NSManaged public var observation: VNFeaturePrintObservation?
```

You don't have to do anything special to use this property.

Incidentally, `Codable` doesn't apply here, because Core Data doesn't use `Codable`. `NSSecureCoding` will convert to/from `Data` automatically, and it's what you need to use with Core Data.

Comment: I also had to add `Vision` in the `Module` field to get the autogenerated code to work.